# How can I prevent SESSID stealing?

Tags: appsec, web-application, cookies, session-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you secure a web app from FireSheep without using SSL?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1322/can-you-secure-a-web-app-from-firesheep-without-using-ssl)

How can I prevent someone on same network from stealing SESSIONID and using it in his own browser (it would mean that he can "log in" without any passwords) without using HTTPS ?

Is there any way in PHP to check/prevent/detect it?

If it's more suitable for StackOverflow, please move it someone

Comment: Hi @genesis, welcome to the site! I closed this question, since it's already been well answered in several other questions on this site - see esp. the linked question. Also please read the [FAQ], and browse through the site a bit - I'm sure you'll find more relevant information.

Comment: Sorry, I did not found anything by search. I think I was searching bad keywords. Execuse me