# Is authentication through proxy sites safer?

Tags: authentication, privacy, webserver, proxy, threats

usually in office or wherever whenever we are blocked with gmail and facebook websites,we used to browse the site with the proxy sites,we used to pass our login data through proxy sites,my question is since we are exploring through proxy servers,is it there any high risks evolve around while using proxy sites?

is it possible for them(sites) to track down my data?If yes how to prevent it?

Comment: Who is "them"? Do you mean the administrators of the proxies, or the sites themselves?

Comment: @GdD sites mate

Comment: What data do you mean, and what is your concern with proxies as opposed to non-proxy connections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of increased risks from using proxies, yes there could be.  If you browse a site which sends things like a session token in clear-text, it would be possible for the proxy to see/use that token.  so to an extent you need to trust the proxy server operator not to do that.

If you are using a proxy I'd be especially aware of any SSL errors that might indicate that your session is being intercepted as well.

In terms of whether it's possible for the end-point sites to track you down that depends on a number of factors.

This kind of question has been discussed elsewhere on the site, so I'd take a look at some of the answers like [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2398/different-strategies-for-online-anonymity-and-their-s), and a good list of posts [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13416/whats-the-best-way-to-make-my-internet-traffic-anonymous)