# How secure/private is the browsing history on browsers?

Tags: privacy, web-browser, logging

I've been using Aviator secure browser for a while which insists that you run private mode by default (cookies and history wiped after every session), which makes me wonder how secure the history is in other browsers? Is it really necessary to wipe your history since nobody except you should have access to it or does your browser share your history with sites you visit, like it does with cookies?

So I guess my question is how vulnerable your history in your browser is for outside attacks. Is it private (only viewed locally) in most cases?

Comment: History is not shared. The purpose for 'private mode' to be private from other people using your computer (family, coworkers, etc.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do the various browser "private modes" do?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16545/what-do-the-various-browser-private-modes-do)

Comment: The most important part of @Christian's answer isn't actually the answer to your question, but this:  Don't use Aviator.  It is unsupported and has significant security issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aviator has had actual security (not privacy) [issues](http://www.zdnet.com/article/avoid-aviator-browser-if-you-care-about-security-and-privacy-google-warns/) and is nominated for this year's [Pwnie awards](http://pwnies.com/nominations/).

In general, browsers will not share your history with websites you visit. There have been vulnerabilities in [multiple browsers](http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/06/theyre-ba-ack-browser-sniffing-ghosts-return-to-haunt-chrome-ie-firefox/) that would allow a website to get your browsing history or guess if you have visited some specific websites or not.

The vulnerability above could not have worked when using private mode because that instance of the browser didn't have access to your browser history.